# Autocomplete off in django crispy form

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I am new in crispy form configuration. I have a django form and want to setup autocomplete = off thoughout the form. I found this attribute can be set within field widget. But instead of individual input , how can we apply whole form in a single line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify this at the `<form>` tag, for example:

```
<form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="some-url">
    {% crisply my_form %}
</form>
```

or if you work with a `FormHelper`, you can specify the `attrs`:

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.attrs['autocomplete'] = 'off'
```

That being said, turning `autocomplete` off is sometimes a security hazard, since it sometimes forces users to use *simple* passwords, over more complicated ones. Therefore some browsers start to ignore this attribute.

Comment: self.helperattrs['autocomplete'] = 'off' should be self.helper.attrs['autocomplete'] = 'off'. I have changed that and working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could add this in the `__init__()` method of your form:

```
for fields in self.fields.values():
    field.widget.attrs['autocomplete'] = 'off'
```